# Using more Subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

While I was using subqueries, I came across this situation. Could any one explain me which one is efficient and also, the situations where case 1 is better than case 2 or vice versa.

In case 1, I have used 3 subqueries and in total of 4 select operations, it need to perform.

**CASE 1**

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE Cid = (SELECT  cid FROM s WHERE id = $sid) 
  AND Bid = (SELECT bid FROM s WHERE id = $sid) 
  AND Eid = (SELECT eid FROM s WHERE id = $sid)
```

In case 2, I have retrieved some values from database and  perform mysql query again. Here mysqli_query is performed twice but in the case 1 only once we have used.

**CASE 2**

```
$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cid,bid,eid FROM s WHERE id = $sid");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_ASSOC);

"SELECT * FROM t WHERE Cid = $row[cid] AND Bid = $row[bid] AND Eid = $row[eid]";
```

or any other better solution? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.  You don't need subqueries when you can use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT t.* FROM t
JOIN s ON t.Cid = s.cid AND t.Bid = s.bid AND t.Eid = s.eid
WHERE s.id = $sid
```

Comment: i was going to post the same...you deserve a +1 sir.